# documention for the Glassfish ACC (Application Client Container)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, iiop

I found this bit of information about the ACC (Application Client Container):

> The ACC uses the IIOP ORB to contact the server during injection. The
>   default port for the ORB is 3700. The Java Web Start support
>   automatically sets the ORB-related properties to point to the correct
>   ORB address. If you are running a cluster then this includes all
>   currently-active cluster members' ORBs.

https://www.java.net/node/679235

However, the documention, in general, seems light.  While it is mentioned in the Development Guide:

> Introducing the Application Client Container
>
> The Application Client Container (ACC) includes a set of Java classes,
>   libraries, and other files that are required for and distributed with
>   Java client programs that execute in their own Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM). The ACC manages the execution of Java EE application client
>   components (application clients), which are used to access a variety
>   of Java EE services (such as JMS resources, EJB components, web
>   services, security, and so on.) from a JVM outside the Oracle
>   GlassFish Server. The ACC communicates with the GlassFish Server using
>   RMI-IIOP protocol and manages the details of RMI-IIOP communication
>   using the client ORB that is bundled with it. Compared to other Java
>   EE containers, the ACC is lightweight. For information about debugging
>   application clients, see Application Client Debugging.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition Application Development Guide Release 4.0

also:

> The Application Client Container.
>
> Although accessing an EJB from a client using JNDI is simpler than in
>   EJB 2.x, it is still rather awkward. The good news is that we can
>   dispense with JNDI altogether if the client runs from within an
>   application client container (ACC). The EJB 3 specification does not
>   mandate that an EJB-compliant application server provides an ACC but
>   makes its inclusion optional. Consequently not all EJB-compliant
>   application servers provide an ACC, however GlassFish does.

http://www.developer.am/ejb3/?page=application-client-container

it's more of a general description.  There's no official documentation on the ACC and its usage specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The Application Development Guide contains some sections (only available as PDF?):

https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf

https://glassfish.java.net/documentation.html